Main menu (in LTS 24.04 with Lubuntu) is broken; missing a Programming or Development category
Questions:  Is my menu broken?  If so, how can I fix it?  If not, what am I doing or not doing for an entire menu category to be hidden or missing?  I assume all programs should know how to add themselves to the app menu, and to add a category to it if it's not yet there;  but maybe I'm naive.  On my older laptop, with 22.04 and Lubuntu, the main menu works fine.  Conditional extra question: If I have to manually add the Programming category, how do I put entries to development apps I already installed?  Reinstall them?
In more detail:
I put together a new PC and installed LTS 24.04 on it, and then Lubuntu;  but my main menu ("appmenu"?) in Lubuntu is lacking a Programming category, and installing development tools for C/C++, Rust and Python leave no link entries anywhere.
I'm an eternal newbie with linux, and I don't even know where the file that controls my menu entries should be.  I looked everywhere in the hidden folders under my home directory and found nothing resembling a menu file.  I searched here for answers before hitting the Ask Question button.  I found something that looked marginally promising;  somebody was recommending to run pcmanfm to fix a lubuntu menu problem, so I tried it, and it produced output alarming to my newbie eyes, which I paste below in case it provides any clues to this problem:
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: GFileInfo created without standard::edit-name
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1742 (g_file_info_get_edit_name): should not be reached
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: GFileInfo created without standard::size
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: GFileInfo created without standard::edit-name
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1742 (g_file_info_get_edit_name): should not be reached
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1845 (g_file_info_get_size): should not be reached
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: GFileInfo created without standard::content-type
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1821 (g_file_info_get_content_type): should not be reached
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: GFileInfo created without standard::size
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1845 (g_file_info_get_size): should not be reached
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: GFileInfo created without standard::is-symlink
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1676 (g_file_info_get_is_symlink): should not be reached
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: GFileInfo created without standard::is-symlink
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1676 (g_file_info_get_is_symlink): should not be reached
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: GFileInfo created without standard::is-backup
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1654 (g_file_info_get_is_backup): should not be reached
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: GFileInfo created without standard::is-hidden
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1632 (g_file_info_get_is_hidden): should not be reached
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: GFileInfo created without standard::is-backup
(pcmanfm:92334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:41:59.691: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1654 (g_file_info_get_is_backup): should not be reached
(pcmanfm:92334): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:41:59.691: Theme parsing error: <data>:2:27: The style property GtkWidget:focus-padding is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(pcmanfm:92334): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:41:59.691: Theme parsing error: <data>:3:30: The style property GtkWidget:focus-line-width is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version'''

The hardware is MSI X670E mobo, Ryzen 5 7600, using internal GPU for now.  Not that any of this should have anything to do with the problem, but just for the record.
Thanks in advance.

This answer might give you a bit more insight how the applicationmenu is organized. It does not fully answer your question, just some details.

I used Lubuntu from 14.04 to 18.04 because I insist on having total control of the menu entries on my system and I had figured out how to do that in LXDE. After 18.04 they changed Lubuntu completely so I fled to the MATE desktop. It allows you complete control of the menu system. If that's important to you (as it is to me) consider a trial install of MATE or playing with it in a virtual machine to see if it meets your needs. The transition from Lubuntu to MATE was pretty easy from a user point of view and now I like it better.

Thanks, I will read about how menus work;  and I might give MATE try if I can find it.  EDIT:  Lol, I have Mate already installed, apparently...

As an aside to my answer: in 24.04, you should most definitely be using pcmanfm-qt and not pcmanfm. If you have both LXDE and LXQt installed and/or if you're using components of one in the other, I could see it potentially creating problems. Running the default file manager in the command line would not result in all that spew you got.

There are, unfortunately, some incorrect assumptions here. Being Freedesktop/XDG compliant, as really all the different flavors/desktop environments are, the menu is populated based on Desktop Entries. Not all packages include such entries, which means they don’t show up in the menu at all. Furthermore, some packages include Desktop Entries which don’t include categories (it’s not required for autostarting, for example) or use unexpected categories.
Also, as most programming packages do not include graphical applications, they naturally do not add anything to the menu. It doesn’t mean you can’t add them, but it’s kind of unexpected behavior. As an example, the rust-all package includes numerous binaries, but not a single Desktop Entry.
There is a simple solution: add an entry yourself to $XDG_DATA_HOME (should be ~/.local/share/applications) like so:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=string description
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/binary
Categories=Development;

Note I didn’t use “Programming” for the category as it’s not a registered option and thus not guaranteed to show up in the menu. Despite this, the category shown in the menu is “Programming.”

I found an answer to this problem, if anyone ends up in a similar bind.  Apparently Lubuntu does not know how to add a category to the menu.  I was back at standard ubuntu and I installed a development package there, from the Apps Center;  then, on coming back to Lubuntu, the Programming menu entry had been added.  However, the other development packages I had installed in Lubuntu before, had no entries under Programming.  I'm hoping that re-installing the packages will fix that.
EDIT:  It did fix that.  Also, I abandoned lubuntu for MATE, as was suggested to me;  complete control of the menu, and a much better window system.  Night and day.
